# How see drivers loading order in windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, bsod

I have changed motherboard and got bsod immediately when windows 10 log in screen shown. (E.g. I can see user, picture, type coupe of symbols in password area but after couple of seconds I got BSOD). BSOD itself does not provide any information except `system_exception` keyword.

I enabled boot logging and got the following (from ntbtlog.txt):

```
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Version 10.0 (Build 17134)
 1  2 2019 03:33:37.500
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\hal.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\kd.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\mcupdate_AuthenticAMD.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\msrpc.sys
```

So BSOD appread when `msrpc.sys` is loaded. I googled and know that this means a driver problem. The question is - how to know what exactly driver leads to bsod? Have windows any settings for output drivers loading?

Comment: Are you able to get into windows at all, using safe mode or anything? Also, do you have a second computer available for you to work on?

Comment: There should be a system dump file created when it bsod's, you would need to windbg this file to find the real cause......https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools

Comment: You can try this utility for a fast debug......https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not en universal solution but helps for me:

I disabled all programs from startup and everything works. In my case there was Realtek auto start program which uses absent audio device. After removing Realtek and install new driver everything became working.